# Get value in multiline string YAML

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to get the value of `port` using Python and PyYAML in the code below:

```yaml
values: |-
  services:
    port: 80
```

My script:

```py
import yaml

with open('service.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)
    
port = data.get('values', {}).get('services', {}).get('port', {})
services = port
print(port)
```

My output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 13, in <module>
    port = data.get('values', {}).get('services', {}).get('port', {})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

If I trying without multiline string, it's working.

Comment: You have a string of YAML. Maybe you should use a YAML parser...

Comment: `If i trying without multiline string, it's working.` Why put a multiline string in your YAML document like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a YAML string as a the value of the `values` key.  If you are stuck with this odd format, you'll have to parse the YAML string of `values` a second time:

```py
import yaml

with open('service.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)

values = data.get('values', {})
services = yaml.safe_load(values).get('services', {})
port = services.get('port', {})
print(port)
```

Output:

```
80
```